# Disabling Spring Security leads to Failed to load application context

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

I am disabling Spring Security for the **test** profile as below:

```
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: test
  autoconfigure:
    exclude[0]: org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.reactive.ReactiveManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration
    exclude[1]: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.reactive.ReactiveSecurityAutoConfiguration
```

Error:

```
Failed to load ApplicationContext
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/reactive/ReactiveOAuth2ClientConfigurations$ReactiveOAuth2ClientConfiguration$SecurityWebFilterChainConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'springSecurityFilterChain' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Answer (score 1):

A small clarification that you are not disabling Spring Security, you are disabling the Spring Boot auto-configuration of Spring Security. You can read more about that in the Spring Boot [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.security).

In your configuration you are disabling the `ReactiveSecurityAutoConfiguration`, but the `ReactiveOAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration` is still enabled, presumably because you have a dependency such as `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client`.

As described in the error message, the `ReactiveOAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration` is attempting to create a `SecurityWebFilterChain` bean, but cannot inject the required `ServerHttpSecurity` bean, because the `ReactiveSecurityAutoConfiguration` is disabled.

To fix the error message, you can disable the OAuth 2.0 client auto-configuration as well.

```
spring:
 autoconfigure:
    exclude[0]: org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.reactive.ReactiveManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration
    exclude[1]: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.reactive.ReactiveSecurityAutoConfiguration
    exclude[2]: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.reactive.ReactiveOAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the okta-spring-boot-starter and this worked for me:

```
spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude:
      - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.reactive.ReactiveOAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration
      - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.reactive.ReactiveOAuth2ResourceServerAutoConfiguration
      - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.reactive.ReactiveSecurityAutoConfiguration
```